# Unit testing spring cloud gateway filters with spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm adding cookies in gateway response using reactive global filters as:

```
chain.filter(exchange).then(<a mono relevant to response>)
```

When I'm trying to test this using spock *then* method is not invoked from the stubbed Mono.

The filter itself:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange)
            .then(refreshCookiesMono(exchange));
}

private Mono<Void> refreshCookiesMono(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        //interactions with *exchange* and *chain*
    });
}
```

This test passes despite 0 * _ in the end:

```
@Subject
CookieFilter cookieFilter = new CookieFilter(cookieHelper)
...
ServerWebExchange exchange = Mock ServerWebExchange
GatewayFilterChain chain = Mock GatewayFilterChain
Mono<Void> mono = Mock Mono

...

def "cookieFilter refreshes the cookie with a new value"() {
    given:

    when:
    cookieFilter.filter(exchange, chain)

    then:
    1 * chain.filter(exchange) >> mono
    0 * _
}
```

But in the code I invoke *.then* from the  mono returned from *.filter* method.

Why isn't *mono.then()* taken into account? Of course when I try to test all the underlying logic - spock doesn't find interactions.

Comment: Where is `cookieFilter` coming from in the test? Is it another mock?

Comment: @jaco0646 nope, it's an actual implementation that uses one of the mocks as a dependency. I've updated the question.

Comment: So, `cookieHelper` is a mock, but it is not invoked as part of this test?

Comment: @jaco0646, yes. chain.filter(..) also returns a mock and mono.then() interaction is not taken into account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Losing hope to test the filter end-to-end I've extracted my runnable in a separate package private method and tested it without Monos and any other reactive things.

The code in my filter now looks like:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange)
            .then(Mono.fromRunnable(refreshCookies(exchange)));
}

Runnable refreshCookies(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return () -> {
        //magic happens here ....
    };
}
```

Any further clues and refactoring proposals are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`chain.filter(exchange)` returns the instance of mono that you've mocked.

*You haven't specified any expectations on that mock* (and this is the answer to your question, I believe), so the test doesn't really check the Filter, it only checks that there was one call to `chain.filter(exchange)`.

Besides, Spock supports Stubs in additions to Mocks, and unlike many other frameworks there is a difference between those:

Mocks are "heavier" and you can do verification(s) on them (in "then" block), stubs are much more "lightweight" and you usually can specify expectations on them in a "given" block.
Usually you use Mocks if you want to mock some interaction and base the test on the protocol that gets managed around this interaction, in other cases Stubs are preferable.

Comment: I put *exchange* and *chain* as mocks inside the method. Then I interact with them in method's body. Due to 0 * _ in the end the test should fail if any unmatched interactions happen. It doesn't fail. When I add "1 * mono.then(_)" to "then" section the test fails with "Too few invocations... 0".